# Create entire highchart object on server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I'm following this [example](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-file-csv-xml-json#3)
to load a highchart using data from the server (I'm using a file here for testing purposes). I'd like to be able not only to load the data from the server but the entire instead.
As I understand, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kh5jY/) simple chart example shows that the entire chart is a json object, so I thought If I create the json code exactly like this and load it into an object and then pass it to the chart it would work. In an attempt to do that, I came up with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
                    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(data);
                });
            }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is my data.json file:

```
{
    chart: {
        type: 'bar',
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Fruit Consumption'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit eaten'
        }
    },
    series: [
        {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [1, 0, 4]
        }, 
        {
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 7, 3]
        }
    ],
}
```

I'm not getting any errors however the chart does not load. I appreciate any help.

Comment: Log `data` to the console, and see if it’s exactly the object structure your are expecting. Apart from that: Live example, please.

Comment: I tried to log data to the console, but looks like the getJson function is not getting executed. Sorry about the live code, I also tried to create a JSFiddle with an example but I don't have an account and Fiddle is not permitting to sign up at the moment due to SPAM bots. I'll create the example as soon as the sign up becomes available. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: You don’t need to sign up for jsfiddle to save a fiddle …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed. The problem was with my data.json file. the getJson function wasn't working because the data.json wasn't a valid json file as it expects all the properties quoted as string otherwise it won't work.
I've formatted the file correctly used JSONLint validator and now it looks like this:

```
{
    "chart": {
        "type": "bar",
        "renderTo": "container"
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "Fruit Consumption"
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "categories": [
            "Apples",
            "Bananas",
            "Oranges"
        ]
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": "Fruit eaten"
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Jane",
            "data": [
                1,
                0,
                4
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "John",
            "data": [
                5,
                7,
                3
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The chart is rendering fine now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` object lacks [`renderTo`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.renderTo) property of the `chart`, which is needed to actually render the chart, which might also be a problem.

You can set it to `document.body` for example, and your chart will be rendered fine.

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tDVxd/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have the renderTo property set on my original code, just forgot to put it in the example. Your doesn't simulate what I want to achieve though. Your defining the chart statically into a variable and not loading it from an external json file, or a server if you will.<br>The problem seems to be with the getJson function as it looks like it isn't getting executed. Any ideas?